# Hooks or Events to reduce coupling between packages

Tags: php, laravel, events, module, hook

What is the best approach to reduce coupling between modules?

For example, if I have an `Invoice` package and it is related to the`Customer` package.

What I understand is that I would have to use a system of "hooks" to inject, for example, a tab with the list of customer invoices in the edit view of a customer.

And in turn, use an event system to know, from the perspective of the "Invoice" package, when, for example, someone tries to delete a client.

What I want to achieve is to reduce the coupling so that if I delete the invoice package, the client package is not affected.

How can I get it? Using Laravel's event system? Using a custom class like the following?

My Hooks class:

```
class HookRepository
{
/**
 * The repository items.
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
protected $items;

/**
 * Create a new repository instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->items = collect();
}

/**
 * Dynamically call methods.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $arguments
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call(string $method, array $arguments)
{
    return $this->items->{$method}(...$arguments);
}

/**
 * Register a new hook callback.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $hook
 * @param  callable  $callback
 * @param  int  $priority
 * @return void
 */
public function register($hook, callable $callback, int $priority = 10): void
{
    $this->items->push(compact('hook', 'callback', 'priority'));
}

/**
 * Apply the callbacks on the given hook and value.
 *
 * @param  string  $hook
 * @param  array  $arguments
 * @return mixed
 */
public function apply(string $hook, ...$arguments)
{
    return $this->items->filter(function ($filter) use ($hook) {
        return !! array_filter((array) $filter['hook'], function ($item) use ($hook) {
            return Str::is($item, $hook);
        });
    })->sortBy('priority')->reduce(function ($value, $filter) use ($arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array($filter['callback'], [$value] + $arguments);
    }, $arguments[0] ?? null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using interfaces and abstract classes to implement **Open/Close principle** from S**O**LID

1. Identify an interface. What ClassA wants from ClassB
2. Generalize - when you have an interface you will be able to identify common operations that most classes that need to implement it will need it. ( Don't try to future-proof to much here or it will most likely backfire )

Note: If you are doing this in hope you will avoid refactoring your code. Forget it. :) It will only make it a lot easier which already is a huge benefit.

Avoid using hooks to realize Structural and/or Behavioral patterns.

edit>
Neither Package nor Hook is a part of Laravel or Design Patterns lingo.

This itself should give you a hint.

Let me play a guessing game:

```php
    <?php
    PackageInterface {
        public function enable();
        public function disable();
        public function isEnabled();
        public function getHooks(): HookInterface[];
    }
    HookInterface {
        public function injectView();
        // or maybe
        public function injectIntoView($view);
    }
```

It purely depends on your circumstances when you will load your packages and inject something into view.

You can for example `enable()` the Package when `$invoice->wasPaid()` or when Customer enabled the package himself `$customer->enable($package)`

Comment: But with interfaces I cant inject views... I want to allow interactions between packages, but keep coupling low.

Comment: I think i need to use hooks and or events, but i dont know...

Comment: @Mr.Hook "But with interfaces I cant inject views..." I don't think that's the case but I would need a more detailed example to be sure. Remember you define the interfaces and you decide what they define. [link](https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP#patterns)

Comment: When I enabled my Invoices package I want to inject (i guess with hooks) a tab with customer invoices in the edit view of customers.

Comment: And then, if a customer is deleted, i want to delete all their invoices. So, i think i need hooks for views and events for deletes (and other operations, like add new fields to client)

Comment: I need this i I want to keep low coupling, do I can delete invoices package without worry about customer

Comment: Question is what that low coupling is suppose to achieve? If you want to make it framework independent than add another abstraction layer on top of the Eloquent Event System. ( for example [link](https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/main/Behavioral/Observer#observer) If you want to create some kind of Extension / Plugin system inside your app than you have to identify it's components and plan them using that little 2 step method I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Also I would recommend you to avoid using such ambiguous methods as in the example you have provided. It is very hard to debug and you will sooner or later loose track of those events.

Comment: I need events or hooks? (I cant give you +1, because my points, sorry)

Comment: There is any alternative to make what i need?

Comment: Could you give me an example of using interfaces to reduce coupling, using invoices and customers as example?